# Webpack dev server TypeError: callback is not a function when using HotModuleReplacementPlugin

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to implement hot reload using webpack in a react application. Here is config file of webpack that I have managed to make till now:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var combineLoaders = require('webpack-combine-loaders');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000', // WebpackDevServer host and port
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
    './app/StartUp.js'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/../app/assets/webpack",
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ["react-hot", "babel?presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0,presets[]=react,plugins[]=transform-runtime"],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
            'style-loader',
            combineLoaders([{
              loader: 'css-loader',
              query: {
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            }])
        )
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("main.css"),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

But this gives me the following error when I run the command `webpack-dev-server`, which I haven't been able to find a solution to for past couple of hours:

```
webpack: Using compiler.parser is deprecated.
Use compiler.plugin("compilation", function(compilation, data) {
  data.normalModuleFactory.plugin("parser", function(parser, options) { parser.plugin(/* ... */); });
}); instead. It was called at HotModuleReplacementPlugin.apply (/Users/Rai/Documents/github/sarvahitey-core/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/HotModuleReplacementPlugin.js:162:18).
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
/Users/Rai/Documents/github/sarvahitey-core/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NullFactory.js:9
    return callback();
           ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at NullFactory.create (/Users/Rai/Documents/github/sarvahitey-core/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/NullFactory.js:9:9)
    at iteratorFactory (/Users/Rai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:229:12)
    at /Users/Rai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3025:16
    at eachOfArrayLike (/Users/Rai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:941:9)
    at eachOf (/Users/Rai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:991:5)
    at Object.eachLimit (/Users/Rai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3089:3)
    at Compilation.addModuleDependencies (/Users/Rai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:210:9)
    at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (/Users/Rai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:195:8)
    at _this.buildModule.err (/Users/Rai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:335:13)
    at building.forEach.cb (/Users/Rai/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:140:27)
```

Let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Your problem might be that another package is installing a different version of webpack that is being picked up. I had this problem from using react-storybook

Comment: any resolution on this? having a similar issue.

Comment: Yup. Same type of spit happening using electron webpack builder. `TypeError: callback is not a function` What makes that even more clucked up is that the *exact* same code was building just fine few days back. Just seems to intermittently when running `yarn` - guess I have to update something?